# Text without hyphenation with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, hyphenation

How do I get the text does not break the line?
I have

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[align=left,text width=3cm] {Contemplando a contemporaneidade};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

but i need

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just increase the `text width`? (By the way, your example code does not break the line if I put it into a `article` or `minimal` document. Do you set anything that influences the font size?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Or don't specify the text width at all, just add a line break at the appropriate position.

```
\node[align=left] {Contemplando a\\contemporaneidade};
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using `align=left`, you can use `align=flush left`. This seems to do exactly the same as `align=left`, but without the hyphenation.

```
\node[align=flush left,text width=3cm] {Contemplando a contemporaneidade};
```

I found this trick here: [Manual/automatic line breaks and text alignment in TikZ nodes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123671/manual-automatic-line-breaks-and-text-alignment-in-tikz-nodes)

Comment: Also works with `align=flush center` and `align=flush right`

Answer (score 3):

Increase the value for `text width` conveniently.

Answer (score 3):

We could use `\hyphenchar\font` as a global switcher; `=1` turning on hyphenation, `=-1` preventing hyphenation.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[align=left,text width=2cm,draw] {Contemplando a contemporaneidade};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[align=left,text width=2cm,draw] {%
  \hyphenchar\font=-1 % 1 or -1
  Contemplando a contemporaneidade
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\hyphenchar\font=1 % 1 or -1
Regular document. Regular document. Regular document. Regular document. Regular document. Regular document. Regular document. 
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: Is the `\hyphenchar\font=1` necessary to restore hyphenation, or is the `\hyphenchar\font=1` actually localized? I ask because you called it a global switcher. At first glance, it seems to me that it would be a change valid only within the tikzpicture's scope.

Comment: @macmadness86 I am not 100% sure, but I think that I tried % \hyphenchar\font=1 and it wasn't working well. I am not TeXing these days, so I cannot try more experiments, I am sorry about that.