# Manual/automatic line breaks and text alignment in TikZ nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, line-breaking, nodes

How can I insert a line break in a TikZ node? Simply putting `\\` where I want the break doesn't work (see MWE).

Is there a way to make lines break automatically at some specified width?

And can I control the alignment of the text (left, right, centered, justified)?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node {First line\\second line};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Of course you're writing this to provide a standard answer for this usual requirements. Nice idea!

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Oh, and the first question you linked to (http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50902) has a really bad accepted answer. I know that the votes show this, but I still see potential for confusion there.

Comment: I have a very rough and short template in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63469/3235 in case anyone wants to write a canonical answer.

Comment: Section 16.4.3 "Text Parameters: Alignment and Width for Multi-Line Text" in the 2.10 PGF manual seems to provide most (if not all) of the relevant information.

Comment: @Jake The "really bad accepted answer" is not bad: it is the _first_ solution gives by pgfmanual! ;-)

Comment: @PaulGaborit: Oh, good point. Nonetheless, I think for the majority of cases, that shouldn't be the preferred approach.

Comment: @Jake You are absolutely right.

Comment: @PaulGaborit I would go with the *bad*. That must be a slip of pen.

Comment: Related (questions that do ask this in any way): [\[1\]](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31096), [\[2\]](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31109), [\[3\]](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50902), [\[4\]](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63469), [\[5\]](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88664), [\[6\]](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63469), [\[7\]](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/123670)

Comment: Who is Community that gives out the reputation?

Answer (score 423, accepted):

The problem, according to the [TikZ-PGF manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) is that

> Normally, when a node is typeset, all the text you give in the braces is put in one long line (in an `\hbox`, to be precise), and the node will become as wide as necessary (§17.4.3).

Now, the TikZ-PGF manual explains three ways to achieve line breaking inside of a TikZ node if one desires.

1. Use a multi-line environment inside of the node.

---

One can use an environment inside the node that forces line breaking or creates a line-breaking environment to achieve line breaking inside the node. The example in the manual uses the `tabular` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [draw] (example-tabular) {
\begin{tabular}{cc}
eaxmple1 & example2 \\
example 3 & example4 \\
\end{tabular}
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

2. Use `\\` and `align`.

---

If you want to insert line breaks manually, you can use `\\` and the optional argument `align`. (If you do not specify an option for `align`, the line breaking will not happen, and the problem noted by the OP will occur.)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (example-align) [draw, align=left]{example \\ example example};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

The advantage to this option is that the node's size is automatically set to the width of the longest line inside the node, as can be seen in the accompanying image, where the width of the node is set to the width of the second line. However, the disadvantage to this solution is that you have to manually control the line breaking yourself (more on this below).

It is also worth noting that you can control the spacing of the lines via an optional argument of the `\\` command:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (example-align) [draw, align=left]{example \\[5em] example example};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Note, however, that the `\\` cannot be nested inside of a group. So, for example, the following will **not** work.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (example-align) [draw, align=left]{\textbf{example \\ example example}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Instead, you would need to do:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (example-align) [draw, align=left]{\textbf{example}\\\textbf{example example}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

3. Use `text width` and `\\` (and maybe `align`, too).

---

Finally, the third option noted in the TikZ-PGF manual is to use the `text width` argument, which, I believe, internally creates a `minipage` environment. This solution manually sets the width of the node, and it can then be used in conjunction with manual line breaking:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (example-textwidth-1) [draw, text width=3cm]{example \\ example};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Additionally, it can be used with a lengthier block of text whose default width is greater than the width specified via `text width`. In such cases, the text will automatically wrap inside a box of the specified width:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (example-textwidth-2) [draw, text width=3cm]{This is a demonstration text for showing how line breaking works.};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

The `text width` argument can also be used in conjunction with the `align` argument to produce different effects. The options for `align` are `left`, `flush left`, `right`, `flush right`, `center`, `flush center`, `justify`, and `none`. See §17.4.3 for the details of the different effects of these `align` options in conjunction with the `text width` argument.

In brief, however, the `flush` variants do not try to balance left and right borders via hyphenation. In my opinion, the result often does not look good (see picture), but it can be used if, for whatever reason, you do wish to avoid hyphenation.

[image]

(The top node in the picture immediately above uses `align=left`, and the bottom node uses `align=flush left`.)

### A fourth option

A fourth, and I think the preferred option not discussed in the TikZ-PGF manual, is to use the [`varwidth`](http://ctan.org/pkg/varwidth) package. This package essentially creates a `minipage` environment but automatically sets the horizontal size of the environment to the widest thing inside of it. Above, you will notice that the `text width` option often made the node bigger than necessary. For example, in the picture reproduced immediately below, you can see that there is extra space at the right margin:

[image]

However, if we use the `varwidth` package, this extra space is eliminated, *even though both are set to* `3cm`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (example-textwidth-3) [draw, text width=3cm, align=left]{This is a demonstration text for showing how line breaking works.};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (example-varwidth) [draw, align=left] {\begin{varwidth}{3cm}This is a demonstration text for showing how line breaking works.\end{varwidth}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Discussion

Overall, I think the fourth option is the most preferred, as it makes the node as compact as possible (unless, of course, you do *not* want the node to be compact).

Nonetheless, there are at least two cons to the fourth option that I can think of that you may want to consider before determining how you wish to implement multi-line text inside of a TikZ node, though I think the first con to this option has a workaround.

The first con is the following: as @percusse pointed out in the comments, the `varwidth` package effectively does the same thing as what `align` does to the node, which presumably causes `varwidth` to effectively moot any visible differences between the possible options for `align`. So, if you wish to have a right-aligned margin in your node and you specify it via `align=right`, there will be no visible difference between that and, say, `align=left`. This can be overcome, though, by making use of the [`ragged2e`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e) package. If you do want your node to have a right-aligned margin yet you also want it to be as compact as possible (and do not want to take the time to manually manipulate the setting of `text width` via a 'guess and check' method):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (example-varwidth-left) [draw, align=left]{\begin{varwidth}{3cm}This is a demonstration text for showing how line breaking works.\end{varwidth}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (example-varwidth-right) [draw, align=right]{\begin{varwidth}{3cm}This is a demonstration text for showing how line breaking works.\end{varwidth}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (example-varwidth-ragged) [draw, align=flush right] {\begin{varwidth}{3cm}\RaggedLeft This is a demonstration text for showing how line breaking works.\end{varwidth}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the image, you can see that there is no difference between the first two nodes, but using the commands made available by `ragged2e` does produce a visible effect in the third node.

The second con to the fourth option arises if you really do wish to control the line breaking manually. The `varwidth` environment still attempts to balance lines via hyphenation, which can lead to, in my opinion, ugly results:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (example-varwidth-linebreak) [draw, align=left]{\begin{varwidth}{3cm}This is a demonstration \\ text for showing how line breaking works.\end{varwidth}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

If you wish to manually control the line breaking, I would suggest the second option, specifying the `align` argument and inserting `\\`'s as you please.

**Update (as per @percusse's comment)**:

In the case of wanting to manually control line breaks, the second option is preferable to the fourth option because the second option sets the node width to the length of the longest line inside of the node. No text wrapping and no hyphenation is enforced. As a result, there will be no, in my opinion, 'ugly' output from the second option precisely because no text wrapping and hyphenation is enforced.

Moreover, this is why I have included the fourth option in addition to the three noted in the TikZ-PGF manual. If you do wish to enforce text wrapping inside of the node with a certain width *as well as have the node's size as compact as possible*, then you will want to use the `varwidth` environment. Compare the following two nodes, one with `align` and one with `varwidth` set to `3cm`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (example) [draw, align=left]{This is a demonstration text for showing how line breaking works.};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (example) [draw]{\begin{varwidth}{3cm}This is a demonstration text for showing how line breaking works.\end{varwidth}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

---

### Addendum

Strictly speaking, this addendum is outside the scope of the question; however, given the intended nature of this question as indicated in the comments on the question, I thought that I would add that you can put any of the list environments (`itemize`, `enumerate`, and `description`) inside of a node by embedding it inside either a `minipage` or `varwidth` environment. Again, I think the `varwidth` environment is preferable for reasons enumerated (no pun intended!) above.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [draw] (example-list) {
\begin{varwidth}{3cm}
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*]
\item{First item}
\item{Second item}
\end{enumerate}
\end{varwidth}
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @percusse Ah, that would explain why the effects of `align` are mooted in conjunction with the `varwidth` environment. A question, though: how does TikZ determine the width of the node when you only specify `align`. `varwidth` gives the user the option of setting at least an approximate width, and then any extra space is effectively chopped off. That (along with my apparent ignorance) is why I added it as a fourth option---namely, since it gives the user the ability to at least roughly specify the width of the node for herself.

Comment: @percusse Okay, so it seems `align` only sets the width of the node to the minimal width, whereas `varwidth` does this **and** enforces text wrapping and hyphenation. I've updated my answer a bit to reflect this, though if you have any clarifications or more nitpicks, I'd appreciate more helpful comments. Thanks! :-)

Comment: @Adam Ah, sorry. I coudn't check it yet. But as far as I remember it was all about controlling something like a `\pgfutil@minipage` environment when it is not a `\....@line@box` (!?). I need to read the code before I say something stupid.

Comment: @percusse I'm still relatively new to (La)TeX, so I'm still learning my way around things. Your last comment is a bit beyond me, but if you do find anything further to nitpick in the updated answer, let me know. Thanks again! :-)

Comment: Am I right if I say there cannot be different modes of text alignment in a single tikz node (e.g. center and right)?

Comment: @Viesturs In the simplest case, I think you're right. But there's no reason you couldn't create multiple `minipage` or `varwidth` environments inside of a node, each with their own text alignment.

Comment: @AdamLiter Your answer about this possibility inspired me to launch a separate question - https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/387233/multiple-alignment-in-a-tikz-node

Comment: Now that the manual has changed a lot and the page number changes, you could quote the section number/name instead. "17.4.3 Text Parameters: Alignment and Width for Multi-Line Text"  _____________________________________________________________________________________________ Also note that in option 2, the ``\\`` **must not be in any group**  like in a `tabular` environment.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just looking to break down the line at your points of reference, it suffices to break down the node itself to multiple lines.

For instance, from TikZ manual section 3.12, the code draft below

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) -- (3,0) 
  node [above,align=center,midway]
  {
    First line \\
    Second Line
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

breaks the line with no further packages/tools required.

NOTE: this method did not work for me when the node is alone; just when it is part of a line. No extra packages are needed though.

**The script output**:

[image: Output of the TikZ script with no extra packages]

Comment: Don't know why this don't work for me.

Comment: it only works when `align` is provided.