# Use \ref as part of a graphic

Tags: graphics, cross-referencing

Is it possible to make a reference as part of a graphic, which is included in a LaTeX document?
If so, what would be the preferred format for such a graphic (EPS, ...)?

Mockup:

[image: Mockup]

I'm using pdflatex for compiling.

Comment: Does the reference point to something inside the same document, or elsewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do this would be to put the `\includegraphics{...}` inside of a TikZ `node`, and then put another `node` on top of the image with TikZ, where this node either contains the `\ref{...}` or the `\label{...}` command, depending on whether you want a reference or a label inside of the picture.

The code below for overlaying using TikZ with the `\includegrpahics{...}` is taken from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz) on TeX.SX.

The `varwidth` package is used to put an `enumerate` environment inside of a TikZ `node`. See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123671/manual-automatic-line-breaks-and-text-alignment-in-tikz-nodes/124114#124114) for an explanation.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\begin{document}

Here, we will reference a label that is set on top of the picture with \verb|tikz| (\ref{fig:1}).

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth]{example-image}};
    \node at (1.2,2) {\begin{varwidth}{2in}\begin{enumerate}[label={Fig.~\arabic*}]\item{Hi, let's reference this\label{fig:1}}\end{enumerate}\end{varwidth}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

Here, we will do the opposite of this; we will put the \verb|\ref{...}| inside the \verb|node|, as a reference to example 1:

\begin{enumerate}

    \item{\label{ex:1}Example 1}

\end{enumerate}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth]{example-image}};
    \node at (1.2,2) {Look at example~\ref{ex:1}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]