# Qtree Text Positioning

Tags: tikz-pgf, line-breaking, tikz-qtree

My document looks like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree,tikz-qtree-compat}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\title{}
\author{}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%

\begin{tikzpicture}[level 1/.style={level distance=1cm}]

\Tree
[.(-,(3,3),1) 
[.(1,(8,0),2) 
                  [. (1,(1,1),1) {(1,(1,1),$\perp $)\\ (-1,1)} ] 
                  [.(1,(1,1),2) [.(1,(1,1),1) {(1,(1,1),$\perp $) (-1,1)} ] ]
                  [.(1,(8,0),1) (1,(8,0),$\perp $)  ]
               ] 
 [.(-,(3,3),2) 
                                [.(2,(0,8),1) 
                                                        [.(2,(1,1),2) {(2,(1,1),$\perp $)} ]
                                                        [.(2,(1,1),1) {(2,(1,1),2)} ]
                                                        [.(2,(0,8),2) {(2,(0,8),$\perp $)} ]]
                 { (-,(3,3),$\perp$)} 
              ]
]

\bigskip
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The text `(-1,1)` (in the first indented line) should appear below the leaf, but when I insert a line break (`\\`), I get an error.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that TikZ doesn't know how to break the lines. If you add the option `align=center` to the options for the `tikzpicture` environment, the problem is resolved.

For more information, see the [PGF Manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf), section 16.4.3, page 179, or [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124114/24113) to a similar question.

Comment: See also §3.1 of the `tikz-qtree` manual (last tree in the section.)