# How to draw a thin rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I was trying to draw a rectangle like this (there would be only one letter per row in the rectangle). But none of `\\`, `\linebreak`, `\newline` seems to work. How can I do this?

[image]

Well, I tried this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm, auto]  
\tikzset{
    man/.style={rectangle}
}  
\node[man] (man) {A \\ B \linebreak C \newline D};
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a complete minimal working example showing your current code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, in your question it would have been interesting to say that there were other parts with Tikz. Without other parts Code Mocker is right with the use of `\parbox` but you need to fix the width.

Perhaps it's possible to consider your question like a duplicate one : [manual-automatic-line-breaks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123671/manual-automatic-line-breaks-and-text-alignment-in-tikz-nodes) and you can also read the **pgfmanual 16.4.3 Text Parameters: Alignment and Width for Multi-Line Text**

*I prefer to give another answer with some explanations.*

If you put a simple text in a node, this text is written inside a `\hbox`. Inside this box, `\\` is ineffective. If you want to be able to use linebreak you need to use complex objects like *boxes, \parbox, minipage* etc...

1) First idea like in the pgfmanual : **tabular**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\tikz \node[draw,fill=blue!20] {
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
A\\
B
\end{tabular}
};
\end{document}
```

[image]

2) a **box** with `\parbox` but it's not perfect. You need to know the width of the rectangle

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\tikz \node[draw,fill=blue!20] {
  \parbox{12pt}{\centering A\\B\\C}
};
\end{document}
```

It's also possible to use a `minipage` or a `\vbox`

3) `text width` is  a node option but you need to fix the width like Claudio's code

4) the better one is the use of `align=center` like Claudio's code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\tikz \node[draw,fill=blue!20,align=center] {A\\B\\C};
\end{document}
```

Comment: Using tabular alone without TikZ should be enough, unless we want to slow down the compilation.

Comment: Yes you are right but the OP needs to use Tikz with other parts.

Comment: @AlainMatthes: it seems I've lost a green tick, but welcome back Alain!

Answer (score 13):

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\colorbox{blue!50!green}{\parbox{12pt}{\centering A\\B\\C}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or

```
\documentclass[preview,border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{91,155,213}
\begin{document}
\colorbox{mycolor}{\parbox{12pt}{\color{white}\centering A\\B\\C}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If compilation speed is the most important aspect, avoid using TikZ. :-)

Comment: But I already have many other parts in TikZ.

Comment: No this is not a fine solution because you need to fix the width. A tabular is better

Answer (score 9):

TikZ version.

The simplest manner is to use a node, fixing its `text width` and center align the content; alternatively, you can break the content, provided that you are setting some `align`ment. The third option uses the dedicated `rectangle split` shape.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[text=white,fill=cyan!60!blue,text width=1em,align=center]{A B C};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[text=white,fill=cyan!60!blue,align=center]{A\\ B\\ C};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[text=white,fill=cyan!60!blue,
 rectangle split,rectangle split parts=3]{A\nodepart{two}B\nodepart{three}C};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: you don't need the double backslash in the first example. Whitespace is enough since the width is quite narrow.

Comment: @percusse: sure, I incidentally merged two options into one.

Answer (score 6):

I think the same as the other tikz solutions but a few minutes later:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0.125cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikz\node[fill=blue!70!green!60, text=white, inner xsep=1.5ex, align=center, font=\sf]
  {A\\B\\C};
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is how. use `align=center`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz,xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,arrows}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
mynode/.style={minimum height=2cm, minimum width=1cm, fill=blue, text=white,align=center}
}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mynode] at (0,0) (a){A\\B\\C};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Ti*k*Z node (though this looks overkill in this case):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikz\node[fill=blue!40!cyan, text=white, align=center, font=\sffamily]{A\\B\\C};
\end{document}
```

[image: output]
You have to specify `align` option to use `\\` in Ti*k*Z node.

If you want to increase the spaces between the lines, add an optional argument to `\\`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikz\node[fill=blue!40!cyan, text=white, align=center, font=\sffamily]{A\\[1ex]B\\[1ex]C};
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `TikZ` solution. This one uses a `matrix` node. Each letter will be on a different cell/node which can be individually referenced.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mynode/.style={text=white, 
               fill=cyan!60!blue, 
               anchor=center, 
               inner sep=3pt}]

\matrix (A) [matrix of nodes, inner sep=0pt, 
             nodes={mynode}, column sep=0pt, row sep=0pt] 
             {A\\B\\C\\};

\draw (A-1-1) to [out=30, in=-30] (A-3-1);
\node[fit={(A-2-1)}, circle, draw, red, inner sep=-1pt] (r) {};
\draw[<-, red] (r) -- ++(15:7.5mm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]