# split rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf

i try to draw a split rectangle like this:

[image]

And this is my current state :/ Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Not necessarily a `rectangle split` is the best approach; for your purpose, I think you can get some insights from [How to draw a thin rectangle](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/157125/13304).

Comment: And what is the code of your current state?

Comment: Add `rectangle split draw splits=false` to splitted node options

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On this task you can use the `tikz` package along with the `array` environment, if you don't need some inside/outside ticks in it. If you do, there are better ways how to get them.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw=blue, fill=blue!30, line width=2pt]
  {\def\arraystretch{1.5}%
  $\begin{array}{c}
  x_1\\ x_2\\[9pt] \vdots\\[6pt] x_n
  \end{array}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Answer (score 3):

An alternative using stacks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\setstackgap{L}{1.6\baselineskip}
\fcolorbox{black}{gray!40}{\ensurestackMath{\Centerstack{\,x_1\, x_2 {} {\vdots} {} x_n}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]