# How to make a line break in a TikZ matrix cell?

Tags: tikz-pgf, line-breaking

Can I use TikZ's own tools to make a line break in the matrix cells or do I have to use a `tabular`-environment or a `\parbox`?

### MWE (doesn't work, I included the faulty code)

```
\documentclass[
11pt
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{
tikz,
relsize,
tgheros
}

\usetikzlibrary{
    calc,trees,shadows,positioning,arrows,chains,
    decorations.pathreplacing,
    decorations.pathmorphing,
    decorations.shapes,
    decorations.text,
    shapes,
    shapes.geometric,
    shapes.symbols,
    matrix,
    patterns,
    intersections,
    fit
}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background layer}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground layer}
\pgfsetlayers{background layer,main,foreground layer}

\tikzset{
    >=latex,
    line/.style={draw, thick, ->},
    phase/.style={
        text height=1.5ex,
        text depth=0ex,
        align=left,
        anchor=center,
        %   text width=6cm,
        font=\sffamily\bfseries\small,
        rectangle,
        minimum height=1.0cm,
        draw=black,
        very thick,
        fill=black!40
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\small,node distance=0.5cm]
\matrix (m) [
matrix of nodes,
nodes in empty cells,
row sep=6mm,
column sep=3mm,
inner sep=7pt
] {
    %
    |[phase]| This should include\\a line break\\
    |[phase], align=center| Here should be a line\\break as well.
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can include `text width` , adjust the `minimum height` and use `{This should include a \\ line break}`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Manual/automatic line breaks and text alignment in TikZ nodes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123671/manual-automatic-line-breaks-and-text-alignment-in-tikz-nodes)

Comment: @HarishKumar Your comment solved the problem. If you submit your comment as an answer, I'd gladly mark it as a reply.

Comment: @percusse The issue here is not a duplicate insofar that matrices made of nodes are usually (or *can be*, to be exact) written without the braces. Yet in this case, they have to be added to make it work.

Comment: @henry True, but I've seen that you are aware of the option passing via `|...|` syntax hence I thought of the duplicate since that makes the question independent from matrix nodes.

Comment: Oh, interesting. Well so far I only knew that `|...|` enables on to write text in nodes like this in matrices, but not in usual TikZ graphics.

Comment: @HarishKumar Y u no post comment as reply? :(

Comment: @henry I have added an answer. Sorry to have missed your comment and the delay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual methods used to have a line break inside a `tikz` node can be applied here also. You can use `text width=<dimesion>` and if you want a break at some specified point, put a `\\` there. But take care to hide it by using braces for otherwise it will be mistaken for the end of row.

```
\documentclass[
11pt
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{
tikz,
relsize,
tgheros
}

\usetikzlibrary{
    calc,trees,shadows,positioning,arrows,chains,
    decorations.pathreplacing,
    decorations.pathmorphing,
    decorations.shapes,
    decorations.text,
    shapes,
    shapes.geometric,
    shapes.symbols,
    matrix,
    patterns,
    intersections,
    fit
}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background layer}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground layer}
\pgfsetlayers{background layer,main,foreground layer}

\tikzset{
    >=latex,
    line/.style={draw, thick, ->},
    phase/.style={
        %text height=1.5ex,
        %text depth=1.5ex,
        align=left,
        anchor=center,
           text width=6cm,
        font=\sffamily\bfseries\small,
        rectangle,
        minimum height=1.5cm,
        draw=black,
        very thick,
        fill=black!40
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\small,node distance=0.5cm]
\matrix (m) [
matrix of nodes,
nodes in empty cells,
row sep=6mm,
column sep=3mm,
inner sep=7pt
] {
    %
    |[phase]| {This should include\\a line break}\\
    |[phase, align=center]| {Here should be a line\\break as well}\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]