# \ganttalignnewline does't work

Tags: pgfgantt

is there a way to break the label of a `\gantgroup`?
It works for `\gantbar`, but it seems not in `\ganttgroup`. Any suggestion?

IT WORKS:

```
\begin{ganttchart}[
hgrid,
vgrid,
newline shortcut=true,
bar label node/.append style=%
{align=left}
]{1}{6}
\gantttitle{Title}{6} \\
\ganttgroup{Group 1 test}{1}{4}\\
\ganttbar{%
This is a\ganttalignnewline
multi-line text.%
}{1}{3}
\end{ganttchart}
```

IT DOESN'T:

```
\begin{ganttchart}[
hgrid,
vgrid,
newline shortcut=true,
bar label node/.append style=%
{align=left}
]{1}{6}
\gantttitle{Title}{6} \\
\ganttgroup{Group 1\ganttalignnewline test}{1}{4}\\
\ganttbar{%
This is a\ganttalignnewline
multi-line text.%
}{1}{3}
\end{ganttchart}
```

Comment: This problem seems very similar to [Manual/automatic line breaks and text alignment in TikZ nodes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/123671/5764).

Answer (score 6):

I can confirm that `\ganttgroup` **cannot** split strings, although I, just like the author of the original post, tried:

- Inserting `\ganttalignnewline` like this:

> \ganttgroup{Group 1\ganttalignnewline test}{1}{4}\
>
> Inserting `\newline` or `\\`
>
> I sent an email to the author, Wolfgang.

**UPDATE**:

A temporal solution is this:

> `\ganttgroup{   \parbox[c][1ex][c]{0.03\textwidth}{Some \\ text}     }{2017-04}{2019-03}  \\`

where you can adjust `0.03\textwidth` at your taste. Ugly hack, but it works.

**UPDATE 2**:
From the email of the author of ganttchart (Wolfgang):

the trick is to enable line breaking in the group label, e.g. by specifying group label `node/.append style={align=right}` as optional argument to \ganttgroup. Consider the following example:

```
\begin{ganttchart}{1}{12}
\ganttgroup{This is \ganttalignnewline Group 1}{1}{2} %% will not work
\ganttgroup[group label node/.append style={align=right}]{This is \ganttalignnewline Group 2}{1}{7} %works!
\end{ganttchart}
```

Comment: I assume any of the methods listed in [Manual/automatic line breaks and text alignment in TikZ nodes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/123671/5764) would work, as you're attempting to break a line in a TikZ node. It depends on whether you want to fix this globally or locally.