# Multiline label for shape 'tape' in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, nodes

I would like to draw a tape in tikz with a multiline label in it. The normal way of just using `\\` doesn't work here.

MWE

```
\documentclass[tikz,border={5pt}]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols,shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{
multidocument/.style={
shape=tape,
draw,
fill=white,
tape bend top=none
}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [multidocument]{Multi line\\Label};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to add an alignment to the node, for instance, `align=center` after `tape bend top=none`.

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/123671/32374

Comment: @darthbith Great, thank you. I should have looked at my other .styles where I have an alignment defined.