# How to make a multiline Tikz node with different alignments?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Tikz allow to make multiline nodes using `align=alignement` where alignement can be `left`, `center` or `right` and `\\` ([see this previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123671/manual-automatic-line-breaks-and-text-alignment-in-tikz-nodes))

I am wondering how one can have a multi line node with a different alignement depending on the line ?

Example:

```
   Node title

this the body of  the
node spanning several
lines.
```

Comment: Can you give an example of such text? Not much hope for word breaking though.

Comment: I just added a simple text example. i don't need word breaking in this case

Comment: See for example `\node[text width=3.5cm,draw,align=justify]{
\centering Node title

this the body of the node spanning 
several lines.
};` You need an empty line after `Node title` otherwise `\centering` won't work.

Comment: Can you show a working example, I am not able to compile my document when using \centering.

Comment: Complete example: `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}\begin{document}\begin{tikzpicture}\node [draw,text width=5cm,align=justify] {{\centering Stuff \par}\lipsum[1]};\end{tikzpicture}\end{document}` This isn't really different from normal text, a `node` with `text width` set is something like a `minipage`.

Comment: Thanks ! I was just missing the text width parameter thinking it was not important !

Comment: Heck, just stick a \parbox inside the node.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. that looks like an answer to me. Any chance you want to convert it into one?

Answer (score 2):

When adding the `text width` parameter to a `node`, this is similar to the node contents being within a `minipage`. As such, with `text width` set you can use any normal way of centering text, such as `\centering` or the `center`  environment.
If you want the remaining text to be justfied, add `align=justify` to the node options as well, the default is to set the node text ragged right.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [draw,text width=5cm]
{{\centering Stuff \par}
\lipsum[1]};

\node at (6,0) [draw,text width=5cm,align=justify]
{\begin{center}
Stuff
\end{center}
\lipsum[1]};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry to put this as an answer but I'm new and can't comment the previous answer. If, like me, you only have two lines and the first is not a title, you can add a negative `\vspace` inside your `center` environment to centre the whole text within the box.