# How can I make my pgfplots title multiline

Tags: pgfplots

I tried `title = {really\\ long title}` but it does not work.

One thing that I find is working is to use `title = {\parbox{0.4\textwidth}{\centering really long title}}`. But this is not as flexible. Is there a way that I can break my title into multiline easily?

Comment: The title is created using a TikZ `node`, so [Manual/automatic line breaks and text alignment in TikZ nodes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123671/manual-automatic-line-breaks-and-text-alignment-in-tikz-nodes) applies here. You can set the properties of the title node using `title style={<options>}`.

Comment: @Jake Thanks! Very informative and very helpful!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The title is created using a TikZ node, so [Manual/automatic line breaks and text alignment in TikZ nodes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123671/manual-automatic-line-breaks-and-text-alignment-in-tikz-nodes) applies here. You can set the properties of the title node using `title style={<options>}`. For example, you could set `title style={align=left}, title={really\\long title}` to break the line manually.