# text not rendering inside node

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

In my document I have a diagram that is using tikzpicture to show a few boxes with some descriptive text inside the borders of the boxes. So far I've been having troubles with the formatting which is especially bad when I have introduced newlines:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,oneside,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,shapes,decorations.pathreplacing}

\tikzset{
myStyle/.style={draw, rectangle, text height=3pt, text depth=13pt,
  align=center,fill=gray!30}
}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=-\pgflinewidth]
\node[myStyle] (a) {line one\\line two};
\node[myStyle,right=of a] (b) {command};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I'm attempting to render text that is centered vertically in the node box using the above code. (If the code example can be made more minimal please edit)
When run the text currently does not render inside the shaded box:

[image: Current Output]

What do I need to use to get the text vertically centered within the box?
After reading this question [Manual/automatic line breaks and text alignment in TikZ nodes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123671/manual-automatic-line-breaks-and-text-alignment-in-tikz-nodes) I suspect the problem lies with my styles but I'm not sure what changes to make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `text depth` and `text height` values are too short. It would be better to set a `minimum height`:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,oneside,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,shapes,decorations.pathreplacing}

\tikzset{
myStyle/.style={draw, rectangle,minimum height=2.5\baselineskip,
  align=center,fill=gray!30}
}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=-\pgflinewidth]
\node[myStyle] (a) {line one\\line two};
\node[myStyle,right=of a] (b) {command};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]