# Typesetting two lines of code in a node command

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the following code, `TikZ` is to draw four nodes at the vertices of a parallelogram.  In two of the nodes, I would like to put two lines of text.  I indicate this using `//`.  I thought that using the `contents` option would allow for that.

To draw the edges of the parallelogram, should I first label the coordinates something like A, B, C, and D, and proceed to issue a command like `\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle`?

What is the command to put the nodes in the foreground?  What is the command to add a bit of space between the border of the node at `(2,4)` and the two line segments going toward it?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
        \usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,shapes,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}        
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\path (0,0) node [red] {origin}
(1,3) node[blue]{node contents={upper \\ left}}
(2,4) node[green]{diagonal}
(3,2) node[node contents={lower \\ right}] ;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Partial duplicate: [Manual/automatic line breaks and text alignment in TikZ nodes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/123671/5764)

Comment: @Werner  Yes, that was helpful.  Thanks.  I added `\draw (0,0) -- (3,5) -- (8,8) -- (5,3) -- cycle;` to draw the parallelogram.  To a programmer, would it be more prudent to first declare these coordinates with `\coordinate` command?

Comment: Are you searching for just moving the node so the text doesn't cover the shape? If so you can use `xshift` and `yshift`.

Comment: @Christopher  How would I move the label "origin" diagonally away from the parallelogram?  I used the positional argument `anchor=north east` but I would like to move it a little more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to move the nodes so they don't interfere with the shape you can you `xshift` and `yshift` to fine tune their positions. You can also use anchors as you suggested.

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}  
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=yellow] (0,0) -- (3,5) -- (8,8) -- (5,3) -- cycle;
\node[red, xshift=-1em, yshift=-1em] at (0,0) (A) {origin};
\node[blue, yshift=1em, xshift=-1em] at (3,5) (B) {\begin{tabular}{c}
upper \\
left \\
\end{tabular}};
\node at (8,8) [green, yshift=1em, xshift=1em] (C) {diagonal};
\node at (5,3) [yshift=-1.5em, xshift=1em] (D) {\begin{tabular}{c}
lower \\
right \\
\end{tabular}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

As a note on the colour, remember you can use `fill=yellow!20` to change the shade by varying the number.

Comment: Very nice!  What units of the `xshift` and `yshift` are allowed?  You used `em`.  I guess you can use `mm`, `cm`, and `pt`. Can you use the coordinate system?  

There is one more feature that I would like to add to your display. How do I color the region enclosed by the parallelogram yellow?

Comment: You can indeed use those units, I tend to use `em` as it is a relative unit. I'm not sure what you mean by using the coordinate system. As for colouring the shape you just add `[fill=yellow]` as an option to draw. I'll update the answer to reflect this.

Comment: @ Christopher  I plotted the vertices of the parallelogram using the coordinate system.  If you type `xshirft=-0.1, yshift=-0.1`, would that move a vertex diagonally?  Thanks for the code to color the region enclosed by the parallelogram.

Comment: I don't think this will work as there is no unit. You could create a different node and place it using the coordinate system though. Why you would want to though is a mystery.

Comment: You're right. I can "shift" the node by positioning it differently.  I am looking for consistency in all the displays in a chapter.  Having just started to familiarize myself with `TikZ`, I have not decided how to consistently "shift" nodes.

Answer (score 4):

Why all that typing?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[red,fill=yellow] (0,0) node [below left,red] {origin} --
(3,5) node[blue, align=center,above left]{upper \\ left} --
(8,8) node[green,above]{diagonal} --
(5,3) node[below right,align=center]{lower \\ right} -- cycle ;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  In an effort to familiarize myself with `TikZ`, I was separating the declaration of nodes indicating the vertices of a parallelogram in a `\path` command from the drawing of its edges in a `\draw` command.