# A display in a pie chart that is not expected (or wanted)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have code for a pie chart that is not giving the display that I expected.  There are two aspects of this display that I want changed.  First, I want to have `5%` on the line below `Clothing`.  I have tried the commands

```
\path (O) -- node[pos=0.75,pin=225:Clothing \\ 5\%] {} (225:3);
```

and

```
\path (O) -- node[align=left,pin=225:Clothing \\ 5\%] {} (225:5);
```

but the `\\` seems to be ignored.  Second, I want the pin to be in the direction of 225 degrees.  I thought `(225:3)` in these commands would get this in the display.

What part of the code has the pin coming from the `above right` point on the node?  What does `pos=0.75` instruct `TikZ` to draw?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}   


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[pin distance=5mm]

\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\draw (O) circle (3);
\draw (O) -- (0:3);
\draw (O) -- (90:3);
\draw (O) -- (216:3);
\draw (O) -- (234:3);
\draw (O) -- (288:3);

\path (O) -- node[align=left]{Food \\ 25\%} (45:3);
\path (O) -- node[align=left]{Rent and \\ Utilities \\ 35\%} (153:3);
%\path (O) -- node[align=left,pin=225:Clothing \\ 5\%] {} (225:5);
\path (O) -- node[pos=0.75,pin=225:Clothing\\ 5\%] {} (225:3);
\path (O) -- node[align=left]{Other \\ 5\%} (261:3);
\path (O) -- node[align=left]{Car \\ 20\%} (324:3);

\node[above=33mm of O] {\textbf{David's Monthly Expenses}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Other is probably meant to be 15%.

Comment: I hope that now you are satisfied with received answers. Except that they for writing of shares use ``siunitx`` (what is good idea) are the same as I give you in previous your questions ... Sometimes help to formulate question again that you see, what you omit from received answer in your further use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Line breaks are enabled, if option `align` is given:

`\path (O) -- node[pos=0.75,pin={[align=center]225:Clothing\ 5\%}] {} (225:3);`

Instead of nested nodes, a node can be placed and a line drawn:

```
\draw (225:4) node[align=center] (tmp) {Clothing\\5\%} (tmp) -- (225:2.5);
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pin distance=5mm]

\draw
  (0, 0) coordinate (O)
  circle (3)
  \foreach \i in {0, 90, 216, 234, 288} {
    (O) -- (\i:3)
  }
;

\path[every node/.style={align=center}]
  (O) -- node {Food \\ \SI{25}{\percent}} (45:3)
  (O) -- node {Rent and \\ Utilities \\ \SI{35}{\percent}} (153:3)
  (O) -- node {Other \\ \SI{5}{\percent}} (261:3)
  (O) -- node {Car \\ \SI{20}{\percent}} (324:3)
  (225:4) node (Clothing) {Clothing\\ \SI{5}{\percent}}
;
\draw (225:2.5) -- (Clothing);

\node[above=33mm of O] {\textbf{David's Monthly Expenses}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

In the former case, `pos=.75` is used as starting point for the line of the `pin` option.

Comment: `pos=0.75` starts from what point?

Comment: @user74973 The node with the position is put on the line from `(O)` to `(225:3)`.

Comment: You told me that to get text in a node on different lines, I have to use `align`.  I used `align=left` in the command  `\path (O) -- node[align=left,pin=225:Clothing \\ 5\%] {} (225:5);` and I do not get `5%` on a separate line.  (This was in my original code.)

Comment: @user74973 The `align=left` is applied to the outer node with the empty text. In my answer you can see, that I applied the `align` option to the `pin` node.

Comment: I am not familiar with your `foreach` command and `\SI{25}{\percent}`.  How do I edit the command `the \path (O) -- node[pos=0.75,pin=225:Clothing \\ 5\%] {} (225:3);` to get `5%` below `Clothing`?

Comment: @user74973 Package `siunitx` is the state of the art package for typesetting units and numbers. The package has [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf). Of course, you are free to set the percent numbers the way you like. But, AFAIK, a space is missing between the number and the percent sign in the question.

Comment: @user74973 `\foreach` is documented in the  [manual for TikZ](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf). TikZ is so powerful, that things can be done in many different ways. The example in my answer is just an example to show such a different way.

Comment: @user74973 I do not like the left aligned entries in the image of the question, thus I have used `align=center`. Replacing `center` by `left` should not be to difficult? I have written my example in such a way, that this can be changed in one place instead of going through all nodes.

Comment: I agree.  I was just imitating what I saw in a book.  I decided to center the text in the nodes.  After do so, I still do not get `5%` under `Clothing`.  How do I edit the command the `\path (O) -- node[align=center,pos=0.75,pin=225:Clothing \\ 5\%] {} (225:3);` to get `5%` below `Clothing`?

Comment: @user74973 Look at the second line of my answer.

Comment: How do I "apply the align option to the pin node" in the command  `\path (O) -- node[align=center,pos=0.75,pin=225:Clothing \\ 5\%] {} (225:3);` to get `5%` below `Clothing`?

Comment: @user74973 What's the difficulty reading the second line of my answer? I have even made the relevant part bold.

Comment: Is this your "second line"?  "The `align=left` is applied to the outer node with the empty text. In my answer you can see, that I applied the align option to the pin node."  As you can see from the command that I have sent you twice now, I have put `align=center` in it and I am not getting `5%` on its own line.

Comment: @user74973 The first line of the answer is "Line breaks are enabled, if option `align` is given:" and the second line is "`\path (O) -- node[pos=0.75,pin={[align=center]225:Clothing\ 5\%}] {} (225:3);`".

Comment: I was looking at "comments."  OK.  I see that you have the `pin` option within the node, and within the `pin`, you have the option `[align=center]`.  By the way, you need to have "Clothing \\ 5%"; you have "Clothing \ 5%."

Answer (score 2):

It's probably easier if you use the actual node and then pin "nothing" to it so that it looks like the opposite. As far as I know you cannot apply a line break unless it's a node.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}   


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[pin distance=1cm]

\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\draw (O) circle (3);
\draw (O) -- (0:3);
\draw (O) -- (90:3);
\draw (O) -- (216:3);
\draw (O) -- (234:3);
\draw (O) -- (288:3);

\path (O) -- node[align=left]{Food \\ 25\%} (45:3);
\path (O) -- node[align=left]{Rent and \\ Utilities \\ 35\%} (153:3);
\path (O) -- node[pos=.80,text width=2cm,align=left,pin=45:] {Clothing\\ 5\%} (225:5);
\path (O) -- node[align=left]{Other \\ 5\%} (261:3);
\path (O) -- node[align=left]{Car \\ 20\%} (324:3);

\node[above=33mm of O] {\textbf{David's Monthly Expenses}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I see that you have `pin=45:{}`.  Why do you say this is easier?  I guess that since you are "pinning nothing," you have to have `text width = 2cm`.  This is guessing that I would prefer to avoid.

Comment: What part of the code has the pin coming from the `above right` point on the node?

Comment: @user74973 Sorry, I was not here. Where do you see guessing? The `text width` command is needed to set a maximum so you can go to a new line. `pin=45` is the direction of the pin, in this case, 45 degrees (up right).

Comment: I used the command `\path (O) -- node[pos=0.75, pin={[align=center]225:Clothing \\ 5\%}] {} (225:3.5);` to get the display that I wanted.  (Heiko Oberdiek used it in his code.)  There is not `tex width` command there.

Comment: @user74973 Yes I saw it. However, although Heiko's solution is better because he managed to apply the line break in a pin, his solution is not that different from mine. You have only a few ways to use the `\linebreak` or similar commands: apply text width, align left and some other. In other words, they're equivalent. See this question: [Manual/automatic line breaks and text alignment in TikZ nodes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/123671/4778)

Comment: I just read it.  Thanks for forwarding it to me.  That was a convenient post to the members of tex.stackexchange.

Comment: @user74973 No problem! Glad you appreciated. :D

Comment: I did ... and I would appreciate your help with two aspects for specifying a pin.   I edited my code in the post to include the command `\path (O) -- node[pos=0.75, pin={[align=center]225:Clothing \\ 5\%}] {} (225:3.5);`.  It gives me what I want, but I do not know why the pin emanates from the `above right` part of the node, and I do not know how to `TikZ` determines how far the pin is to go into the slice (or how far the node is from the slice).