# How to break line inside a node on tikz-qtree?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-qtree

I would like to break a line inside a node.

The code below does not give the desired result:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree} %-----questo è il pacchetto interessante
\tikzset{edge from parent/.style=
{draw,
edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south)
-- +(0,-8pt)
-| (\tikzchildnode)}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree [.CP [.NP \node(wh){what}; ]
[.C$'$ [.I did ]
[.\node[draw]{IP};
[.NP [.Det the ] [.N cat ] ]
[.VP [.V sit ]
[.PP [.P on ]
[.\node[draw]{Comunicaz\\all interesting\\denied of\\activate of....};
[.NP [.Det a ] [.N book ] ]
[.PP [.P about ] [.NP \node(t){$t$}; ] ] ] ] ] ] ] ]
\draw[semithick,->] (t)..controls +(south west:5) and +(south:5)..(wh);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

How can I obtain a normal box without extending its size to accommodate all words)?

Comment: [Potentially relevant](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124114/73570)

Comment: Default is single line for nodes. Key `align` can be used to activate line breaks, e.g.: `\node[draw,align=left]{...}`. However, there is no place for such a large node in your diagram.

Comment: You can also use `text width=<some width>` if you want the lines to be broken automatically. (I'm assuming here you want manual breaks as that is what your code shows.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Heiko Oberdiek commented, fitting a large node into your diagram is rather awkward. If you can't think of a better representation you can always shrink the text inside your large node using `\tiny` or various. Line breaks can be added in a number of ways, if you just want to manually add line breaks the you can use `align`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree} %-----questo è il pacchetto interessante
\tikzset{edge from parent/.style=
{draw,
edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south)
-- +(0,-8pt)
-| (\tikzchildnode)}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree [.CP [.NP \node(wh){what}; ]
[.C$'$ [.I did ]
[.\node[draw]{IP};
[.NP [.Det the ] [.N cat ] ]
[.VP [.V sit ]
[.PP [.P on ]
[.\node[draw, font=\tiny, align=center]{Comunicaz all interesting \\ denied of activate of....};
[.NP [.Det a ] [.N book ] ]
[.PP [.P about ] [.NP \node(t){$t$}; ] ] ] ] ] ] ] ]
\draw[semithick,->] (t)..controls +(south west:5) and +(south:5)..(wh);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why `tabular`? The additional `\tabcolsep`s at the left and right need to be removed: `{@{}c@{}}`. Also the curly braces after `\tiny` can be removed, because `\tiny` does not expect an argument. Alternative: `\node[draw, font=\tiny, align=center] {Comunicaz ...}`

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Quite right, I forgot the add in the `@{}`. I didn't know you could specify the font as tiny as such.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Would you like to provide an answer and I'll retract this one.

Comment: Then I would already have written an answer. Can you improve the answer, thus that I can upvote?

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Updated as requested, I was just trying to be polite.

Comment: Thanks, +1. (Dummy text to get the minimum length of a comment.)