# TikZ: node text splits across lines with too much space if small font sizes are used

Tags: tikz-pgf

I generated a simple block diagram using the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, rectangle, 
minimum height=3em, minimum width=5em, align=left]
\tikzstyle{pinstyle} = [pin edge={to-,thin,black}]

% The block diagram code is probably more verbose than necessary
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,>=latex']
    % We start by placing the blocks
    \node [block, name=message-source] {message \\ source};
    \node [block, name=encoder, right of=message-source, node distance=3.5cm] {encoder};
    \node [block, name=channel, right of=encoder, node distance=3.5cm, pin={[pinstyle]above:\scriptsize noise},
    node distance=3.5cm] {channel};
    \node [block, name=decoder, right of=channel, node distance=3.5cm] {decoder};
    \node [block, name=user, right of=decoder, node distance=3.5cm] {user};


    % Once the nodes are placed, connecting them is easy. 
    \draw [->] (message-source) -- node[name=message, align=center] {\scriptsize message} (encoder);
    \draw [->] (encoder) -- node[name=codeword, align=center] {\scriptsize codeword} (channel);
    \draw [->] (channel) -- node[name=receivedword, align=center, text width=1.75cm] {{\scriptsize received word}} (decoder);
    \draw [->] (decoder) -- node[name=decodedmsg, align=center, text width=1.75cm] {{\scriptsize decoded message}} (user);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I want to draw your attention to how "received word" and "decoded message" are split with "too much line space" for the font size (`scriptsize`).

A fix I tried (with no success) is to limit the height of the text box (similar to how I limit the width of the box), with the `text height` keyword, but this does not work.

An ugly solution I can think of is to manually split the text using `\\`, but also supply a spacing parameter like `\\[0.25em]`, (see [Manual/automatic line breaks and text alignment in TikZ nodes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123671/manual-automatic-line-breaks-and-text-alignment-in-tikz-nodes)) but then I'd have to tweak that for each split...onerous!

What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Could you try : {\scriptsize \shortstack{decoded\\message}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use command for font size together with node text! It should be determined by node parameters:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, rectangle,
minimum height=3em, minimum width=5em, align=left]
\tikzstyle{pinstyle} = [pin edge={to-,thin,black}]

% The block diagram code is probably more verbose than necessary
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,>=latex']
% We start by placing the blocks
    \node [block, name=message-source] {message \\ source};
    \node [block, name=encoder, right of=message-source, node distance=3.5cm] {encoder};
    \node [block, name=channel, right of=encoder, node distance=3.5cm, pin={[pinstyle]above:\scriptsize noise},
    node distance=3.5cm] {channel};
    \node [block, name=decoder, right of=channel, node distance=3.5cm] {decoder};
    \node [block, name=user, right of=decoder, node distance=3.5cm] {user};

    % Once the nodes are placed, connecting them is easy.
    \draw [->] (message-source) -- node[name=message, align=center] {\scriptsize message} (encoder);
    \draw [->] (encoder) -- node[name=codeword, align=center] {\scriptsize codeword} (channel);
    \draw [->] (channel) -- node[name=receivedword, align=center, text width=1.75cm,
                                 font=\scriptsize] { received word} (decoder);  <-- here is correct definition of font size!
    \draw [->] (decoder) -- node[name=decodedmsg, align=center, text width=1.75cm] {{\scriptsize decoded message}} (user);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I change this only at one node, that you see difference:

[image]

**Upgrade:** An alternative coding (for my exercise, however maybe you will like it) of your MWE:

\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,chains,quotes}

\usepackage[margin=0.75in,showframe]{geometry}

```
    \begin{document}
\noindent%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 7mm and 18mm,
      start chain = going right,
     block/.style = {rectangle, draw, 
                     minimum height=3em, minimum width=5em, align=left,
                     on chain},
every edge/.style = {draw,-latex'},
every edge quotes/.style = {auto, text width=17mm, align=center, font=\scriptsize},
 every pin/.style = {in distance=7mm, font=\scriptsize},
   every pin edge/.style = {black, latex'-},
                        ]
% We start by placing the blocks
\node [block, name=message-source]  {message\\ source};
\node [block, name=encoder]         {encoder};
\node [block, name=channel,
       pin=above:noise]             {channel};
\node [block, name=decoder]         {decoder};
\node [block, name=user]            {user};

% Once the nodes are placed, connecting them is easy.
\draw   (message-source) edge["message"] (encoder)
        (encoder) edge["codeword"] (channel) 
        (channel) edge["received word"] (decoder)
        (decoder) edge["decoded message"] (user);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

This, more concise code gives equal result as before. In it I use tikzlibrary `quotes` for labeling arrows between blocks. All definition of styles are concentrated on begin of picture code (the can be put in `\tikzset`, `\tikzstyle` is deprecated). With help of chains library nodes are  in "chain" with distances between them determined by `node distance`.

Comment: @user89, I add an example of more concise code of your picture.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\scriptsize\vbox{received  word}` to reduce space between lines

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, rectangle, 
minimum height=3em, minimum width=5em, align=left]
\tikzstyle{pinstyle} = [pin edge={to-,thin,black}]

% The block diagram code is probably more verbose than necessary
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,>=latex']
    % We start by placing the blocks
    \node [block, name=message-source] {message \\ source};
    \node [block, name=encoder, right of=message-source, node distance=3.5cm] {encoder};
    \node [block, name=channel, right of=encoder, node distance=3.5cm, pin={[pinstyle]above:\scriptsize noise},
    node distance=3.5cm] {channel};
    \node [block, name=decoder, right of=channel, node distance=3.5cm] {decoder};
    \node [block, name=user, right of=decoder, node distance=3.5cm] {user};


    % Once the nodes are placed, connecting them is easy. 
    \draw [->] (message-source) -- node[name=message, align=center] {\scriptsize message} (encoder);
    \draw [->] (encoder) -- node[name=codeword, align=center] {\scriptsize codeword} (channel);
    \draw [->] (channel) -- node[name=receivedword, align=center, text width=1.75cm] {{\scriptsize\vbox{received  word}}} (decoder);
    \draw [->] (decoder) -- node[name=decodedmsg, align=center, text width=1.75cm] {{\scriptsize \vbox{decoded message}}} (user);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: hi salim -- thanks for your answer (I gave it a vote, but I accepted the answer). How did you know that using vbox would work?