# ! Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?

Tags: tikz-trees

I seem to be missing something fairly fundamental about how tikz works... I really can't figure out where my missing semicolon is!

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=10em,
  every node/.style = {draw=none, fill=none}]]
  \node {What are the types of \code{a} and \code{b}?}
  child { \node {\code{int} and \code{int}}
    child { \node{Execute procedure \code{int\_add}. }; }; }
  child { \node {\code{float} and \code{float}}
    child { \node{Execute procedure \code{float\_add}.}; }; }
  child { \node {\code{float} and \code{int}}
    child { \node{Execute procedure \code{float\_plus\_int}.}; }; }
  child { \node {\code{int} and \code{float}}
    child { \node{Execute procedure \code{int\_plus\_float}.}; }; }
  child { \node {\code{string} and \code{string}}
    child { \node{Execute procedure \code{string\_concatenate}.}; }; }
  child { \node {Any other combination}
    child { \node{Raise \code{TypeError}.}; }; };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

- There is a spurious `]` after the options of `tikzpicture` (which doesn't do much harm, but shouldn't be there).
- There are more opening than closing braces.
- The `\node`s within the tree should be just `node`s (without backslash), which do not require terminating semicolons.

.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\code[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=10em,
  every node/.style = {draw=none, fill=none}]]
  \node {What are the types of \code{a} and \code{b}?}
  child { node {\code{int} and \code{int}}
          child { node{Execute procedure \code{int\_add}. }
                }
          }
  child { node {\code{float} and \code{float}}
          child { node{Execute procedure \code{float\_add}.}
                }
        }
  child { node {\code{float} and \code{int}}
          child { node{Execute procedure \code{float\_plus\_int}.}
                }
        }
  child { node {\code{int} and \code{float}}
          child { node{Execute procedure \code{int\_plus\_float}.}
                }
        }
  child { node {\code{string} and \code{string}}
          child { node{Execute procedure \code{string\_concatenate}.}
                }
        }
  child { node {Any other combination}
          child { node{Raise \code{TypeError}.}
                }
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you have two semicolons? Shouldn't there just be one?

Comment: @RenéG Yes, sure, I forgot to remove one.

Comment: How do I get the text to split over multiple lines so it doesn't overlap?

Comment: @RenéG Short answer: use the option `text width=2cm` (or whatever), in `every node/.style` and/or on a per-node basis as `node[text width=2cm]`. Long answer: See ["Manual/automatic line breaks and text alignment in TikZ nodes"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123671/manual-automatic-line-breaks-and-text-alignment-in-tikz-nodes). If you still have questions, it is better to ask a new question visible to all.