# How can I use \\ with \texttt inside a node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, line-breaking, typewriter

Take the following MWE:

I made this node with `tikz` using the normal font:

[image: Node: normal font]

However, I need to use a monospaced font to get the following result:

[image: Node: monospaced font]

Since the node has two lines of text, I would normally do `\texttt{line1\\line2}`. However when I compile it I get lots of errors.

If I do `\texttt{line1}\\\texttt{line2}` it compiles with no errors.

Why can't I use `\\` inside `\texttt{}`? Is there a solution to avoid putting `\texttt{}` on every line of text?

---

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw,rectangle,align=center] {line1\\line2};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `{\ttfamily text1\\ text2}`

Comment: Why not `\node[draw,rectangle,align=center,font=\ttfamily] {line1\\line2};`?

Comment: @Sigur I tried that already, but it only affects to the first line of text. The second line remains with the normal font.

Comment: Primarily this is similar to [Manual/automatic line breaks and text alignment in TikZ nodes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/123671/5764)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Why this use of `\texttt` doesn't work in node text is explained in section 17.4.3 of [the `pgfmanual`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf?lang=en).

> When the node text is parsed, the command `\\` is redefined internally. This redefinition is done in such a way that the text from the start of the node to the first occurrence of `\\` is put in an `\hbox`. Then the text following `\\` up to the next `\\` is put in another `\hbox`.

Thus writing `\texttt{line1\\line2}` in a node will result in two `\hbox`es, the first containing `\texttt{line`, the second containing `line2}`, neither of which will parse correctly.

The above description also shows why the suggestion of writing `\ttfamily line1\\ line2` only produces typewriter font on the first line.

As clemens points out the easiest way to use the typewriter font for the whole node is to pass the argument `font=\ttfamily` to the node.

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrew for your contribution! Now I understand the reason for the errors. Thanks also for pointing me to the relevant section of the `pgfmanual`. By the way, I think clemens should be credited instead of me :-)