# Multipart shapes, left/right align text in node

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tikz-shape

Please, consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[preview,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\tikzset{%
base/.style args={#1/#2/#3}{%
     shape=rectangle split, 
     draw, inner sep=1mm, outer sep=0mm,
     rectangle split parts=2, 
     rectangle split part fill={white,gray!20},
     rectangle split draw splits=false,
     rectangle split part align={left, right},
     node contents={\nodepart{one}  #2
                    \nodepart{two}  #3},
                    }
        }% end of tikzset

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style={minimum width=24mm}]
\node (c1) [base=22mm/one line/two\\ line ];
\end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style={text width=22mm}]
\node (c1) [base=22mm/one line/two\\ line ];
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

In the first case the text is correct aligned and as expected in the second part is not broken into two lines. However, replacing `minimum width` with `text width` nullify left/right aligning of text in nodes' parts (and enable break text in more lines).

Is this a feature? How to convince TikZ that it will right align text  in the second node part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `minimum width` case runs as I expect, `\\` doesn't work unless you put it in a multi-line environment, I've used `varwidth`, but you can see this [gorgeous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124114) for alternatives and explanation.

I'm not an expert, but I think that in the `text width` case, on the contrary, there is `tikz` a bug (*edit*: I thought it was a bug, but it is not, see Zarko's answer).

As you can see in my mwe, I've tried with `varwidth`, `\makecell`, `tabular`, and `\flushright`, but they do not work.

The only solution that works is a `flushright` environment with a vertical alignment adjustment.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\tikzset{%
    base/.style args={#1/#2/#3}{%
        shape=rectangle split, 
        draw, inner sep=1mm, outer sep=0mm,
        rectangle split parts=2, 
        rectangle split part fill={white,gray!20},
        rectangle split draw splits=false,
        rectangle split part align={left, right},
        node contents={\nodepart{one}  #2
            \nodepart{two}  #3},
    }
}% end of tikzset

\begin{document}
    % the first case is easily solvable with varwidth:
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style={minimum width=24mm}]
    \node (c1) [base=22mm/one line/\begin{varwidth}{22mm}{two\\ line}\end{varwidth}];
    \end{tikzpicture}

    % in the second case only flushright with a vertical alignment adjustment works:
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style={text width=22mm}]
    \node (c1) [base=22mm/one line/\vspace{-1.2\baselineskip}\begin{flushright}
    two\\ line  \end{flushright}];
    \end{tikzpicture}

    % these are other solutions that I've tried but DO NOT work
    % varwidth:
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style={text width=22mm}]
    \node (c1) [base=22mm/one line/\begin{varwidth}{22mm}two\\ line\\ \end{varwidth}];
    \end{tikzpicture}
    % \makecell:
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style={text width=22mm}]
    \node (c1) [base=22mm/one line/\makecell{two\\ line}];
    \end{tikzpicture}
    % tabular:
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style={text width=22mm}]
    \node (c1) [base=22mm/one line/\begin{tabular}{r}two\\ line\\ \end{tabular}];
    \end{tikzpicture}
    % \flushright:
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style={text width=22mm}]
    \node (c1) [base=22mm/one line/\flushright two\\ line];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

`minimum width` case with `varwidth`:

[image]

`text width` case with `flusright` and vertical alignment adjustment:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for exhaustive answer! Now I look how to include your solutions in node style (will try latter in the day). Do you maybe know, if someone already made bug report for this?

Comment: Meanwhile I succeed to integrate your solution with ` varwidth` into node style and also discover new one, for which I will write answer. At evening I will ask on chat room, how to check, if some bug is already reported (or I need to read all reports).

Comment: now I have filling, that this is not a bug, rather my misunderstanding, how things works and an undocumented features. See my answer below.

Comment: No, without your answer I will never find own one. And your answer fulfill all my expectation.

Answer (score 1):

In effort to integrate of CarLaTeX solution into node style I discover the following solutions:

```
\documentclass[preview,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
base/.style args={#1/#2/#3}{%
     shape=rectangle split,
     draw, inner sep=0.5mm, outer sep=0mm,
     rectangle split parts=2,
     rectangle split part fill={red!20,white},
     rectangle split draw splits=false,
     minimum width=#1,
     text width=#1-4mm,% <-- added
     rectangle split part align={left, right},% second part is right aligned with left aligned content
     node contents={\nodepart{one}  #2
                    \nodepart{two}  #3},
                        }
                    ]
\node (c1) [base=22mm/one line/longer two lines text];
\end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
base/.style args={#1/#2/#3}{%
     shape=rectangle split,
     draw, inner sep=0.5mm, outer sep=0mm,
     rectangle split parts=2,
     rectangle split part fill={red!20,white},
     rectangle split draw splits=false,
     minimum width=#1,
     text width=#1-4mm,% <-- added
     rectangle split part align={left, right},% second part is right aligned 
     node contents={\nodepart{one}  #2
                    \nodepart[align=right]{two}  #3}% second part content is right aligned
                        }
                    ]
\node (c1) [base=22mm/one line/longer two lines text];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]