# combine two venn diagramms in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I am relatively experienced in LaTeX and Beamer but totally new in TikZ environment.
I have create two Venn diagrams as follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{textblock*}{1.5cm}(0.1cm,0.2cm) % {block width} (coords)
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[blend group = soft light]
    \fill[red!30!white]   ( 90:1.2) circle (2);
    \fill[green!30!white] (210:1.2) circle (2);
    \fill[blue!30!white]  (330:1.2) circle (2);
  \end{scope}
  \node at ( 90:2)    {Élaboration};
  \node at (-1.5,-0.97)   {Fonctionnalisation};
  \node at ( 330:2)   {\underline{Caractérisation}};
  \node [font=\Large] {LMPT};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{textblock*}

\begin{textblock*}{1.5cm}(6.6cm,0.2cm) % {block width} (coords)
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[blend group = soft light]
    \fill[red!60!white]   ( 90:1.2) circle (2);
    \fill[green!60!white] (210:1.2) circle (2);
    \fill[blue!60!white]  (330:1.2) circle (2);
  \end{scope}
  \node at ( 90:2)    {Pluridisciplinarité};
  \node at (-1.5,-0.98)   {Expérience};
  \node at ( 330:2)   {Techniques};
  \node [font=\Large] {Moi};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{textblock*}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Questions:

1. How can I add a box, below the two venn diagrams, with arrows pointing to it that combine the two venn diagrams and containing a text?
2. How can I add text into two lines?
3. How can I get rid of the `textblock` environment?
4. Is it possible to add animation?
   That is first appears the left diagram, then the right and finally the box of question (1).

These are the basic questions but I would appreciate any other susggestions to make this particular frame more fancy.

For completeness, I provide the link where I found the original code for the Venn diagrams:
http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/venn/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways you could do this I think. Below I moved everything into one `tikzpicture`. The normal overlay commands of `beamer`, like `\only` and `\uncover` works also in here, so you can use that for point 4. Point 1 is done by adding a new `\node` at the end of the diagram, and because everything is in one `tikzpicture`, you don't need `textblock`. For point 3 I suppose you mean [Manual/automatic line breaks and text alignment in TikZ nodes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123671)

The third of three slides looks like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]
\uncover<1->{
  \begin{scope}[blend group = soft light]
    \fill[red!30!white]   ( 90:1.2) circle (2);
    \fill[green!30!white] (210:1.2) circle (2);
    \fill[blue!30!white]  (330:1.2) circle (2);
  \end{scope}
  \node at ( 90:2)    {Élaboration};
  \node at (-1.5,-0.97)   {Fonctionnalisation};
  \node at ( 330:2)   {\underline{Caractérisation}};
  \node [font=\Large] {LMPT};
}
\uncover<2->{
\begin{scope}[xshift=6.2cm]
  \begin{scope}[blend group = soft light]
    \fill[red!60!white]   ( 90:1.2) circle (2);
    \fill[green!60!white] (210:1.2) circle (2);
    \fill[blue!60!white]  (330:1.2) circle (2);
  \end{scope}
  \node at ( 90:2)    {Pluridisciplinarité};
  \node at (-1.5,-0.98)   {Expérience};
  \node at ( 330:2)   {Techniques};
  \node [font=\Large] {Moi};
\end{scope}
}

\uncover<3>{
\node [below=1cm,draw] (txt) at (current bounding box.south) {What is this?};

\draw [stealth-] (txt) -- ++(135:2cm);
\draw [stealth-] (txt) -- ++(45:2cm);
}


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How can I put this text (of 1) inside a rectangle?

Comment: @dimitris Oh right, forgot that. Add `draw,` before or after `below=1cm` in the node options.