# Reducing line spacing in a tikz-pgfplots node with line break

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, spacing, nodes, text

I am adding text with `\node` to a graph with the help of the `pfgplots` package. Inside the `\node` text I want a line break. From [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123671/manual-automatic-line-breaks-and-text-alignment-in-tikz-nodes) a solution is to add a text width such as `[text width=0]` which will allow usual line breaks `\\` to be parsed (it works maybe because setting a text width creates a mini page or something like that).

A working example where I add such text width and use `\\` for line break is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}    

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xmin=0, xmax=11,ymin=600,ymax=1000]
    \node (source) at (axis cs:5, 750) [text width=0]{\color{gray} {\tiny line1\\line2}};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

As you can see, I have also reduced the font size to `\tiny` for this `\node`. But the line spacing done with `\\` does not seem to follow this font-size reduction. The line spacing - the distance between the two gray text lines - is simply way too big now. Can reduced line spacing be achieved?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

somehow similar to *@esdd* answer but with even closer lines:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xmin=0, xmax=11,ymin=600,ymax=1000]
    \node (source) at (5, 750) [align=left, text=gray,
                                font=\tiny\linespread{0.8}\selectfont]  
                               {line1\\line2};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You might use the optional argument of `\\`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}    

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xmin=0, xmax=11,ymin=600,ymax=1000]
    \node (source) at (axis cs:5, 750) [text width=0]{\color{gray} {\tiny line1\\[-3ex]line2}};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You have to add `\par` before closing the group:

```
\node (source) at (axis cs:5, 750) [text width=0]{\color{gray} {\tiny line1\\line2\par}};
```

But I think its better to use the node options to change the color and the fontsize of the node text. Additionally I would replace `text width=0` by `align=left`.

Result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfplotsset{every tick label/.append style={font=\tiny}}
  \begin{axis}[xmin=0, xmax=11,ymin=600,ymax=1000]
    \node (source) at (axis cs:5, 750) [align=left,font=\tiny,text=gray]{line1\\line2};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]