# Multiple alignment in a tikz node

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting

In the following code

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontspec}%requires xelatex                                                                                                                                                                      
\usepackage{lipsum}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node(a)[align=center]{\Large \textbf{Introduction}};
  \node(b)[align=left, text width=10cm] at (a.south)[anchor=north]{\lipsum[1]};
  \node(b)[align=right, text width=10cm] at (b.south)[anchor=north]{\textbf{Rīga, August 19, 2017}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which gives the output

[image]

I am forced to use separate `\nodes` `a`, `b` and `c` because a different text alignment is used in each of them.

Can I merge `\nodes` `a`, `b` and `c` into a single node that has multiple text alignment modes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \node(b)[align=left, text width=10cm] [anchor=north]{%
  {\centering \Large \textbf{Introduction} \par}
  \lipsum[1]};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What if I have 3 alignment modes?  I modified my question looking for a more flexible answer.

Comment: One can introduce more alignment modes by adding other switches listed in the bottom table of https://pt.sharelatex.com/learn/Text_alignment, such as `\raggedleft`.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why you use tikz for such a task, but perhaps you have your own reasons. Anyway, here is one way you can obtain three different alignments in a tikz node:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontspec}%requires xelatex                                                                                                                                                                      
\usepackage{lipsum}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node(a)[align=left,text width=10cm]{%
  {\centering\Large\textbf{Introduction}\par}
  {\lipsum[1]\mbox{}\hfill\textbf{Rīga, August 19, 2017}}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: `tikz` looks funny because this is an artificially designed **minimum working example**.