# How to break the text appearing next to arrows in two lines?

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

Consider

```
\begin{tikzcd}
F(X) \arrow[r, "F(f)"] \arrow[d, "\eta_X"'] & F(Y) \arrow[d, "here is a really long sentence"] \\
G(X) \arrow[r, "G(f)"'] & G(Y)
\end{tikzcd}
```

I want to make the text describing the down right arrow break in two lines. I have tried `\\` and `\newline`, but this doesn't work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that with a `\parbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
F(X) \arrow[r, "F(f)"] \arrow[d, "\eta_X"'] & F(Y) \arrow[d, "\scriptsize\parbox{2cm}{here is a really long sentence}"] \\
G(X) \arrow[r, "G(f)"'] & G(Y)
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`\\` or `\newline` doesn't, by default, work in any TikZ node, cf. [Manual/automatic line breaks and text alignment in TikZ nodes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123671/manual-automatic-line-breaks-and-text-alignment-in-tikz-nodes). From that question you'll see that if you set `align=left` (or `center`, or `right`), then you can use `\\`. In this context, you'll need to do

```
"long \\ text"align=left
```

If you have actual text in that label, and not a mathematical expression, you also need to switch to text mode:

```
"\text{long} \\ \text{text}"align=left
```

The `\text` macro comes from `amsmath`.

You might also want to move the label away from the line a bit, and for that you can do for example

```
"\text{long} \\ \text{text}"{align=left,right=2mm}
```

Note the extra braces, used to indicate that both the options belong to the `"text"`. In the complete example below, I also reduced the font size, like Bernard did in his answer.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
F(X) \arrow[r, "F(f)"] \arrow[d, "\eta_X"'] & F(Y)
   \arrow[d, "\text{here is a} \\ \text{really long sentence}"{align=left,right=2mm,font=\scriptsize}] \\
G(X) \arrow[r, "G(f)"'] & G(Y)
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```