# How to have a two-line label in a gantt chart?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfgantt

How can I have a two-line label in a gantt chart when the label is outside of the chart (to the left)? This problem was solved when the label is inline with the bar ([Two-line labels in ganttchart](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/419064/two-line-labels-in-ganttchart)), but it does not work when the label is the left of the chart.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should show a complete, small example which we could use for tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[
    bar label node/.append style=%
    {align=left}
  ]{1}{12}
    \gantttitlelist{1,...,12}{1} \\
    \ganttbar[bar height=1]{two\ganttalignnewline lines}{1}{2} \\
    \ganttbar[bar height=1]{two\\ lines}{1}{2} \\
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks for your help!