# how to draw multiple pictures in a node

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, nodes, tikz-node

I'm trying to draw a diagram with pictures with TikZ. I know that people can direct use `\includegraphics` within a node so that the picture will be placed there. My question is, how do I generate a rectangle-shaped node and place 2 (or more) picture in it, pictures should be placed from top to bottom instead of from left to right (what I get when simply use 2 `\includegraphics`).

Here is an example, consider the top picture called `top_pic.png`, and `bottom` called `botton_pic.png` (another question: how do I place the transform symbol like in picture?)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general: If you want line breaks in a node, look at [Manual/automatic line breaks and text alignment in TikZ nodes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123671/manual-automatic-line-breaks-and-text-alignment-in-tikz-nodes/124114#124114). See Stefan's answer for an example.

<s>But that isn't necessarily convenient here, unless you have the transform symbol as an image or symbol in a font already. Probably better to use separate nodes,</s> Another option, with separate nodes, is to use a `\matrix` as in the following example. The symbol can be drawn using arrow tips from the `arrows.meta` library.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [draw] {
  \node {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}}; \\
  \draw [Circle-{Circle[open]}, thick] (0,0) -- (0,0.75); \\
  \node {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-b}}; \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thx a lot for the solution, it works fine. another question (maybe  a little stupid), how can i adjust the size of matrix?

Comment: @user152531 The size is determined mainly by its contents, i.e. the images and the symbol in the middle, can you be more specific? If you want to modify the "padding" between the images and the frame, change the `inner sep` value, e.g. `\matrix [draw,inner sep=3mm] { ...`. If you want to change the distance between the images and the symbol, modify the `row sep`, e.g. `\matrix [draw,inner sep=3mm,row sep=3mm] {...`.

Comment: i mean to scale the whole matrix at once, cause the pictures are too large, even i can adjust them one by one, but maybe theres a way to adjust the size (like scalebox) of matrix?

Comment: @user152531 I don't really understand why you can't just use `\includegraphics[width=5cm]{filename}` as in my example. You can set the width of both images to the same length by adding `\setkeys{Gin}{width=5cm}` between `\begin{tikzpicture}` and `\matrix`, and using just `\includegraphics{filename}`. That said, you can of course just put the whole `tikzpicture` in a `\scalebox` or `\resizebox`, but you'll probably have to change the length and `line width` of the `\draw` that makes the symbol in the middle so that it fits, so I would change the size of the images.

Answer (score 5):

You could fit the graphics.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (imgA){\includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-a}};
\node[below=1.5cm of imgA] (imgB){\includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-b}};
\node[circle,draw,thick,minimum width=2mm,below=1mm of imgA]  (circleA) {};
\node[circle,draw,fill,minimum width=2mm,above=1mm of imgB]  (circleB) {};
\draw (circleA) -- (circleB);
\node[draw,thick,fit=(imgA) (imgB)]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can put the pictures in a table inside a node. Then use a symbol for the transform symbol, e.g. from `trfsigns.sty`. (The `\raisebox` in the last row is to remove the extra depth added on the last row. I use the depth of `\box11`, which is the `\strutbox`, to get the depth).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{trfsigns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw]{%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}
      \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}\\
      \rotatebox{90}{$\Laplace$}\\
      \raisebox{-\dp11}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
    \end{tabular}%
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could also use multipart nodes, see [PGF manual](http://mirrors.standaloneinstaller.com/ctan/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) Section 67.6 p723.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[rectangle split, draw, rectangle split parts = 3]{
  \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}
  \nodepart{two}
  \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-b}
  \nodepart{three}
  \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-c}
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]