# How to write multiple lines inside a box of flowchart made using TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, flow-charts

I am trying to make a large flow chart. The description in each box (trapezoidal, rectangular, diamond shapes) is quite long, so I want to write them in multiple lines inside the boxes. How can I do that? I tried to use \ \ but it didn't work.
This is picture is what I am trying to achieve (this is made in MS Word).

[image]

Also, if you know any post or tutorial that tells in detail about the usage of the latest version of TikZ, please point me to that.

Comment: I'd put the contents in a `\parbox`.

Comment: Define `text width` and `align=center` for each node.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123671/manual-automatic-line-breaks-and-text-alignment-in-tikz-nodes

Comment: @Wave_Rider03 -- please see if the answer below helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}
%\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,angles,arrows.meta,quotes,intersections}
%\usetikzlibrary{through}

\begin{document}



   \lstset{
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    columns=flexible,
    frame=single,
    framerule=0pt,%
    backgroundcolor=\color{gray!20},%
    xleftmargin=\fboxsep,%
    xrightmargin=\fboxsep,
    language=[LaTeX]TeX,%
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},%
    texcsstyle=*\color{red}\bfseries,%
    texcs={end,begin,documentclass,graphicspath},%
    mathescape=false,escapechar=|,%
    literate={<B>}{\textcolor{blue}{\string\usepackage}}1
    {\{ }{\textcolor{red}{\{}}1
    {\}}{\textcolor{red}{\}}}1
    {[}{\textcolor{green}{[}}1     
    {]}{\textcolor{green}{]}}1     
}
    Taken straight from the pgf manual chapter 17.4.3 Text Parameters: Alignment and 
 Width for Multi-Line Text

\textbf{Option1}--  you can use a {tabular} inside a node


\begin{lstlisting}
\tikz \node [draw] {
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        upper left & upper right\\
        lower left & lower right
    \end{tabular}
};\end{lstlisting}\tikz \node [draw] {
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        upper left & upper right\\
        lower left & lower right
    \end{tabular}
};
\hfill\break
\textbf{Option2}-- use \verb|\\| inside your node to mark the end of lines. This will 
only be done, however, if the align option has been given
\begin{lstlisting}
    \tikz[align=left] \node[draw] {This is an\\align=left demonstration.};
\end{lstlisting}\tikz[align=left] \node[draw] {This is an\\align=left demonstration.};
\hfill\break
\begin{lstlisting}
    \tikz[align=center] \node[draw] {This is an\\align=center demonstration.};
\end{lstlisting}
\tikz[align=center] \node[draw] {This is a\\align =center demonstration.};
\hfill\break
The \verb|\\| command takes an optional extra space as an argument in square brackets.
\begin{lstlisting}
    \tikz \node[fill=yellow!80!black,align=right]
    {This is a\\[-2pt] demonstration text for\\[1ex] alignments.};
\end{lstlisting}
\tikz \node[fill=yellow!80!black,align=right]
{This is a\\[-2pt] demonstration text for\\[1ex] alignments.};
\hfill\break
\textbf{Option3}
\begin{lstlisting}
    /tikz/text width=dimension
\end{lstlisting}
This option will put the text of a node in a box of the given width (something akin to 
a {minipage}
of this width). If the node text is not as wide as dimension, it will
nevertheless be put in a box of this width. If it is larger, line breaking will be 
done.
\begin{lstlisting}
\tikz \draw (0,0) node[fill=yellow!80!black,text width=3cm]
{This is a demonstration text for showing how line breaking works.};
\end{lstlisting}
\tikz \draw (0,0) node[fill=yellow!80!black,text width=3cm]
{This is a demonstration text for showing how line breaking works.};
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answers. This and also the link to another post that you shared in the comments, both helped. I have used the 2nd method of using `\\ `  and  `align` in all my boxes and it worked perfectly. 
If anyone else is facing a similar problem and reading this question, you may also check the post link mentioned in previous comments.