# Chart Label in two lines

Tags: pgfplots, line-breaking, bar-chart

I created the chart below and would like to change the ylabel "Fusionierte Theater" two have each word in one line. Is that possible? I would also like to get "Anstalt" "öffentlichen Rechts" in the legend in two lines. Who can help me?

```
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.9}
\begin{axis}[
   xbar stacked,
   legend style={
   legend columns=3,
       at={(xticklabel cs:0.52)},
       anchor=north,
       draw=none,},
   ytick=data,
   axis y line*=none,
   axis x line*=bottom,
   tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
   legend style={font=\footnotesize,legend cell align=left},
   label style={font=\footnotesize},
   xtick={0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40},
   width=.9\textwidth,
   bar width=6mm,
   yticklabels={{Fusionierte Theater}, 
   {Stadttheater}, 
   {Landestheater}, 
   {Staatstheater}, },
   xmin=0,
   xmax=40,
   area legend,
   y=8mm,
   enlarge y limits={abs=0.625},
   nodes near coords,
   nodes near coords style={text=black,anchor=center},
   visualization depends on=y \as \pgfplotspointy,
   every axis plot/.append style={fill}
]
\addplot[yellow] coordinates
 {(8,0) (14,1) (6,2) (6,3)};
\addplot[green] coordinates
 {(0,0) (8,1) (1,2) (5,3)};
\addplot[orange] coordinates
 {(0,0) (14,1) (0,2) (5,3)}; 
 \addplot[cyan] coordinates
 {(0,0) (0,1) (0,2) (6,3)}; 
\addplot[pink] coordinates
 {(0,0) (2,1) (1,2) (0,3)};
\addplot[red] coordinates
 {(0,0) (0,1) (1,2) (0,3)};
\legend{GmbH,Regiebetrieb,Eigenbetrieb,Stiftung,Anstalt öffentlichen Rechts,Körperschaft öffentlichen Rechts}


\end{axis}  
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{X}
\label{fig:stats}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [Manual/automatic line breaks and text alignment in TikZ nodes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123671/manual-automatic-line-breaks-and-text-alignment-in-tikz-nodes), if you have e.g. `align=left` in the node options you can use `\\` to add line breaks. In your case  that means `yticklabel style={align=right}` for the ticklabels, and `nodes={align=left}` inside the `legend style` for the legend entries.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.9}
\begin{axis}[
   xbar stacked,
   legend style={
   legend columns=3,
       at={(xticklabel cs:0.52)},
       anchor=north,
       draw=none,},
   ytick=data,
   axis y line*=none,
   axis x line*=bottom,
   tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
   legend style={
      font=\footnotesize,
      nodes={align=left}, % <-- added
      legend cell align=left},
   label style={font=\footnotesize},
   xtick={0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40},
   width=.9\textwidth,
   bar width=6mm,
   yticklabels={{Fusionierte\\Theater}, % <-- added linebreak
   {Stadttheater}, 
   {Landestheater}, 
   {Staatstheater}, },
   xmin=0,
   xmax=40,
   area legend,
   y=8mm,
   enlarge y limits={abs=0.625},
   nodes near coords,
   nodes near coords style={text=black,anchor=center},
   visualization depends on=y \as \pgfplotspointy,
   every axis plot/.append style={fill},
   yticklabel style={align=right}, % <-- added
]
\addplot[yellow] coordinates
 {(8,0) (14,1) (6,2) (6,3)};
\addplot[green] coordinates
 {(0,0) (8,1) (1,2) (5,3)};
\addplot[orange] coordinates
 {(0,0) (14,1) (0,2) (5,3)}; 
 \addplot[cyan] coordinates
 {(0,0) (0,1) (0,2) (6,3)}; 
\addplot[pink] coordinates
 {(0,0) (2,1) (1,2) (0,3)};
\addplot[red] coordinates
 {(0,0) (0,1) (1,2) (0,3)};
 
\legend{
 GmbH,
 Regiebetrieb,
 Eigenbetrieb,
 Stiftung,
 Anstalt\\öffentlichen Rechts, % <-- added line break
 Körperschaft öffentlichen Rechts
 }


\end{axis}  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you! works perfectly!

Comment: do you may know how to add one label for the whole x axis?

Comment: @qu33ristan `xlabel={Stuff}`?

Comment: tried it after yticklabels{...}, but it doens't appear...

Comment: @qu33ristan Can look later, don't have time right now.

Comment: cool, thank you! that would be very nice!

Comment: @qu33ristan It's behind the legend, so add e.g. `yshift=-15pt` to the `legend style` in addition.

Comment: thank you so much! works perfectly!

Comment: having an idea how to add black frames around the bars?

Comment: @qu33ristan Without having tested, I think e.g. `\addplot [fill=blue, draw=black] ...`

Comment: great, thank you for your quick reply!