# Put texts in arbitrary place of a page

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to put some texts and some formulas in arbitrary places on several pages. For the formulas I use the package tikzpicture as the following:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (5,-10)  node{
$ \left\lbrace \begin{array} \sin x>0 & 0<x<\frac{\pi}{2} \\ \sin x >0 & \frac{\pi}{2}<x<\pi \\  \sin x<0 & \pi <x<\frac{3\pi}{2} \\  \sin x<0 & \frac{3\pi}{2}<x<2\pi  \end{array} \right.  $
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and there is no problem. But sometimes with the above way I have this problem for texts:  the width of that text is bigger than the width of the page and the tikzpicture does not break the line. For example:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (5,-13)  node{The proof of that theorem in not complete and  we can prove that theorem by another way that you will read it in the coming year
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Is there a command to break lines? Is there a way to put texts in arbitrary spots of a page(with or without tikzpicture)?
(Thank you very much)

Comment: [Manual/automatic line breaks and text alignment in TikZ nodes - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123671/manual-automatic-line-breaks-and-text-alignment-in-tikz-nodes) ?

Comment: Try `\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [right,text width=\linewidth, align=left,
       inner xsep=0pt] {The proof of that theorem in not complete and  we can prove that theorem by another way that you will read it in the coming year};
\end{tikzpicture}`

Comment: Thank you. This is completely true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me extend my comment to an answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance=0mm
                    ]
\node (n1) [left] at (\linewidth,0)
    {$\begin{cases} \sin x > 0 & 0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}      \\
                    \sin x > 0 & \frac{\pi}{2}<x<\pi    \\
                    \sin x < 0 & \pi <x<\frac{3\pi}{2}  \\
                    \sin x < 0 & \frac{3\pi}{2}<x<2\pi  \\
      \end{cases}$};
\node (n2) [below left=of n1.south east,
       text width=\linewidth, align=left,
       inner xsep=0pt] {The proof of that theorem in not complete and  we can prove that theorem by another way that you will read it in the coming year};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]