# text on multiple lines inside tikz baseline with node

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, line-breaking, tikz-node

I would like to have a text on multiple lines within the `TikZ` baseline framework. I try to make myself clear. This is the example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetheme{default}


\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,mindmap,trees,backgrounds}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]
\tikzstyle{na} = [baseline=-.5ex]
\tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0,text opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
      \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}}
    },
}

\tikzset{
  background fill/.style={fill=#1},
  background fill/.default={white},
  fill on/.style={alt=#1{}{background fill}},
}

\tikzset{
  background draw/.style={draw=#1},
  background draw/.default={white},
  draw on/.style={alt=#1{}{background draw}},
}
%
\tikzset{
  background filldraw/.style 2 args={draw=#1, fill=#2},
  background filldraw/.default={white}{white},
  filldraw on/.style={alt=#1{}{background filldraw}},
}


\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[remember picture] \node[coordinate] (#1) {#1};}

\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\tiny}
\setlength\abovecaptionskip{0pt}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.arrows,shadows.blur}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,backgrounds}
\usepackage{verbatim}


\begin{document}


\begin{frame}


 \tikz[baseline]{ \node[background filldraw={green}{white!10},filldraw on=<1->,anchor=base,rounded corners,visible on=<1->] (t1) { Test Test \newline Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test};}


\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This is what I get:

[image]

However, I would like to have the text on multiple lines. I have tried with `\newline` or `\\` but nothing seems to work.

I would like to use `\tikz[baseline]` because I have to link the text to an equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\\` with `align` option in the node.

```tex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}    
\tikz[baseline]{ \node[draw=black, align=center] (t1) { Test Test \\ Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test};}    
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Reference: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124114/133968